Bluetooth Android studio
process_name_ptr:13505 com.example.ibasket
2024-05-02 18:21:55.557 13505-13505 zygote64                com.example.ibasket                  E  Failed to parse /product/etc/mfz.xml: Tinyxml2 error (3): Error=XML_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ErrorID=3 (0x3) Line number=0: filename=/product/etc/mfz.xml
2024-05-02 18:21:55.557 13505-13505 zygote64                com.example.ibasket                  E  MemoryFreeze XMLFile not found
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IBASKET"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity4"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity3"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

MainActivity2.java
package com.example.ibasket;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;


public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnBluetooth, searchDevices;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView btReadings, btDevices;

    //Global variables we will use in the
    private static final String TAG = "FrugalLogs";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    //We will use a Handler to get the BT Connection statys
    public static Handler handler;
    private final static int ERROR_READ = 0; // used in bluetooth handler to identify message update
    BluetoothDevice arduinoBTModule = null;
    UUID arduinoUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //We declare a default UUID to create the global variable
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        //Intances of BT Manager and BT Adapter needed to work with BT in Android.
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        btnBluetooth = findViewById(R.id.btnBluetooth);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        btReadings = findViewById(R.id.btReadings);
        searchDevices = findViewById(R.id.searchDevices);
        btDevices = findViewById(R.id.btDevices);

        Log.d(TAG, "Begin Execution");

        //Using a handler to update the interface in case of an error connecting to the BT device
        //My idea is to show handler vs RxAndroid
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {

                    case ERROR_READ:
                        String arduinoMsg = msg.obj.toString(); // Read message from Arduino
                        btReadings.setText(arduinoMsg);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // Create an Observable from RxAndroid
        //The code will be executed when an Observer subscribes to the the Observable
        final Observable<String> connectToBTObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling connectThread class");
            //Call the constructor of the ConnectThread class
            //Passing the Arguments: an Object that represents the BT device,
            // the UUID and then the handler to update the UI
            ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(arduinoBTModule, arduinoUUID, handler);
            connectThread.run();
            //Check if Socket connected
            if (connectThread.getMmSocket().isConnected()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Calling ConnectedThread class");
                //The pass the Open socket as arguments to call the constructor of ConnectedThread
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(connectThread.getMmSocket());
                connectedThread.run();
                if(connectedThread.getValueRead()!=null)
                {
                    // If we have read a value from the Arduino
                    // we call the onNext() function
                    //This value will be observed by the observer
                    emitter.onNext(connectedThread.getValueRead());
                }
                //We just want to stream 1 value, so we close the BT stream
                connectedThread.cancel();
            }
            // SystemClock.sleep(5000); // simulate delay
            //Then we close the socket connection
            connectThread.cancel();
            //We could Override the onComplete function
            emitter.onComplete();

        });

        btnBluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btReadings.setText("");
                if (arduinoBTModule != null) {
                    //We subscribe to the observable until the onComplete() is called
                    //We also define control the thread management with
                    // subscribeOn:  the thread in which you want to execute the action
                    // observeOn: the thread in which you want to get the response
                    connectToBTObservable.
                            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                            subscribe(valueRead -> {
                                //valueRead returned by the onNext() from the Observable
                                btReadings.setText(valueRead);
                                //We just scratched the surface with RxAndroid
                            });

                }
            }
        });

        searchDevices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Display all the linked BT Devices
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check if the phone supports BT
                if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
                    Log.d(TAG, "Device doesn't support Bluetooth");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Device support Bluetooth");
                    //Check BT enabled. If disabled, we ask the user to enable BT
                    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is disabled");
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            Log.d(TAG, "We don't BT Permissions");
                            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is enabled now");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "We have BT Permissions");
                            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is enabled now");
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is enabled");
                    }
                    String btDevicesString="";
                    Set < BluetoothDevice > pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                        // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
                        for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices) {
                            String deviceName = device.getName();
                            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                            Log.d(TAG, "deviceName:" + deviceName);
                            Log.d(TAG, "deviceHardwareAddress:" + deviceHardwareAddress);
                            //We append all devices to a String that we will display in the UI
                            btDevicesString=btDevicesString+deviceName+" || "+deviceHardwareAddress+"\n";
                            //If we find the HC 05 device (the Arduino BT module)
                            //We assign the device value to the Global variable BluetoothDevice
                            //We enable the button "Connect to HC 05 device"
                            if (deviceName.equals("HC-05")) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "HC-05 found");
                                arduinoUUID = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
                                arduinoBTModule = device;
                                //HC -05 Found, enabling the button to read results
                                btnBluetooth.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            btDevices.setText(btDevicesString);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Button Pressed");
            }
        });

        // Initialize views
        ImageView loltImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        // Set click listener for the lolt image
        loltImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Navigate to MainActivity3
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3.class));
            }
        });
    }
}

ConnectThread.java
package com.example.ibasket;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;


//Class that will open the BT Socket to the Arduino BT Module
//Given a BT device, the UUID and a Handler to set the results
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private static final String TAG = "FrugalLogs";
    public static Handler handler;
    private final static int ERROR_READ = 0;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID MY_UUID, Handler handler) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
        // because mmSocket is final.
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        this.handler=handler;

        try {
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice.
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used in the server code.
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void run() {

        try {
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
            handler.obtainMessage(ERROR_READ, "Unable to connect to the BT device").sendToTarget();
            Log.e(TAG, "connectException: " + connectException);
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }

        // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
        // the connection in a separate thread.
        //manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothSocket getMmSocket(){
        return mmSocket;
    }
}

ConnectedThread.java
package com.example.ibasket;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

//Class that given an open BT Socket will
//Open, manage and close the data Stream from the Arduino BT device
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = "FrugalLogs";
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private String valueRead;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
        // member streams are final.
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
        }
        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
        }
        //Input and Output streams members of the class
        //We wont use the Output stream of this project
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public String getValueRead(){
        return valueRead;
    }

    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0; // bytes returned from read()
        int numberOfReadings = 0; //to control the number of readings from the Arduino

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        //We just want to get 1 temperature readings from the Arduino
        while (numberOfReadings < 1) {
            try {

                buffer[bytes] = (byte) mmInStream.read();
                String readMessage;
                // If I detect a "\n" means I already read a full measurement
                if (buffer[bytes] == '\n') {
                    readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.e(TAG, readMessage);
                    //Value to be read by the Observer streamed by the Obervable
                    valueRead=readMessage;
                    bytes = 0;
                    numberOfReadings++;
                } else {
                    bytes++;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
        }
    }
}

activity_main2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBluetooth"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#AB760A"
        android:text="BLUETOOTH"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.653" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.894"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ylwq" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btReadings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.306"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.857" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchDevices"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:text="Search linked BT devices"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.426"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btDevices"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.523" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

build.gradle (module:app)
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.2'

}

I want to put bluetooth function on this app. After run the app, the bluetooth function cannot work. The logcat error show like this

Xiaomi specific perhaps? This also mentions mfz.xml: https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/hyperos-1-0-stable-release.71170/page-73. Then again that could be a completely unrelated log entry and there's some other issue. Bluetooth requires some permissions for example. The relevant code should be in the question and look for mentions of your own app (com.example.ibasket?) in Logcat.

Done updated, I'm adding the code above

Bluetooth function can not work is not a good error description. Please describe what you do and what is going wrong. Without that we can not help you. BTW fir a Bluetooth problem the layout files are not relevant.

I believe you need to include: location permission to Scan BT: my app will not work without this. Make sure to also enable in your Android Setting to allow Loactions while using App!


You also have to request these 2 permissions during run time in code:
arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
